# ¿Porque me da falla el código al pedir el resto?

Tags: java, netbeans, bucles, operador

estoy empezando a programar y queria saber porque me da falla en el codigo cuando pido el resto entre n e i.
La idea del código es que muestre todos los restos de un número ingresado por consola.
Intente cambiando de lugar las variables pero no funciona de esa manera el operador.

```
public static void main (String [] args){
        
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 0;
        
        do {
            
            n = a.nextInt();
            
            if (n>0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    
                    int resto = n % i;
                    
                    if (resto == 0) {
                        System.out.print(i+" ");
                        System.out.println("");
                    }
                    resto = 0;
                }
            }else if(n == 0){
                System.out.println("Todos los números son divisores de cero.");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Es un número negativo.");
            }
        } while (n>=0);
    }
```

Estoy trabajndo en NetBeans 17

Comment: Saludos. Te falto colocar el error; lo más probable _leyendo tu código_ es que falle en la primer interacción; ya que `i=0` y cualquier número dividido entre `0` da error.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, era justamente eso.
Al cambiar: `for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)` solucionó el problema

Comment: Hola Gabriel es correcto lo que comenta Roberto cualquier numero dividido por 0 te dará un error, si bien al inicializar i a 1 se arregla también podrías colocar un if que valide si i es igual a 0 que no haga nada, pero creo que lo mejor seria dejándolo con i = 1.